# Why can't we see past the observable universe?

Tags: speed-of-light, space-expansion, universe, observable-universe

Why can't we see light from beyond the observable universe?

I've done a lot of research on this and all I've found is unsatisfactory answers and straight up nonsense.

Some claim that the universe "expands faster than the speed of light" beyond the observable universe. Such a claim doesn't even make sense because the units of speed are m/s and for expansion are Hz.
That's like saying "the area of this square is larger than the volume of this cube".

All that the expansion can do to light (as far as I know) is redshift it. And light doesn't have a minimum possible frequency or energy value. So even if the expansion of the universe is very rapid, why does the light of distant objects "never reach us". Surely it still would, just extremely redshifted. In this case it *does* still reach us, and yet the claim is that it cannot.

We often detect redshifted light, and that light has not been slowed down. When we detect it, it still goes at c, even though (in fact a better word than "even though" here is "because") it is redshifted. Light is always propagating at c no matter the reference frame.

More precisely: **does the light *really* never reach us, or can we just not detect it?**

If it never reaches us - why?

If we cannot detect it although it does reach us - why?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble's_law

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150084/discussion-on-question-by-krokodil-why-cant-we-see-past-the-observable-universe); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Hubble law is $v=Hd$. When you multiply H by the distance, you get a velocity (units distance/time). That is what the Hubble law is saying. Once you reach a distance (the cosmic horizon) in which the hubble law tell you that Hd=c, where c is the speed of light,  that means that an object at such distance is moving away from you faster than light. This is not a mistake, the local speed of light cannot be larger than c, but in general relativity space expands, so even massive object can look to travel at more than c.

The light from  a galaxy beyond the cosmic horizon may be sent in your direction, but in your reference frame that light ray will move away from you, because the space  (and distance) created in between the light ray and you grows larger than the distance the light ray makes when trying to  get "closer" to you. So basically, that light will never reach you. The light tries to get to you but too many space is being added in between, so it will never make it.

Comment: Is this answer compatible with special relativity postulate that light travels in all reference frames at the SAME speed $c$ ? So if behind cosmic horizon somebody will shoot photon towards us, and space "gets backwards" faster,- in our reference frame photon still should be going towards us at speed $c$,- otherwise relativity postulate about light speed invariance makes no sense. No ?

Comment: I'm happy with the first paragraph. What you're saying in simple terms is that this recession speed isn't really a speed per se. These m/s are the number of "new metres created between us and the object per second". In this case light will travel thru them at c but there will be too many new metres to reach us. So as soon as the photon covers 3E8m, there will be at least 3E8 new metres in front of it. Is this correct? As for the second paragraph why would the light move away from us? We should still observe it as going at c through space, no?

Comment: Just a recent thought. Maybe expanding universe with acceleration is not an inertial reference frame ? If so, then relativity $c$ speed invariance in this case does not apply and indeed photon can be "stopped" or turned back from us. But I'm not sure what scenario fits best, I'm not that strong in relativity. Hm...

Comment: @Krokodil, yes, that is exactly what happens, you add more space in between, light always move at c if it moves close to you where negligible  space is being added as it travels.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas that is a common  misunderstanding, the correct one is that it moves "locally' at c.

Comment: IF we analyse light speed from inertial reference frame, then yes. But since universe expands with acceleration, my idea was that maybe (just maybe) this somehow changes notion of our inertial reference frame into non-inertial one. If it is so,- no more $c$ constancy applies. That was problem i raised which seems you didn't get it.

Comment: @PatoGalmarini Do we need the word 'locally'? I've heard it before but maybe light still moves through space at c in all cases, just we would see it at another effective speed due to the conflict between the light's peculiar speed and the Hubble flow?

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas yes, I misunderstood your comment. But remember that the speed of light is c for any observer, not just inertial ones.

Comment: @Krokodil yes, by locally it is meant that you measure the speed of light inside  a "small enough" lab. The rest of your comment is correct. If you could  measure it  using objects at cosmological distances, you would be  mixing the effects of both, the actual motion of the object (or light) across space, plus the amount of new distance/space created in between which also contributes to the measured velocity.

Comment: @PatoGalmarini Really ? Have you read [postulates of special relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postulates_of_special_relativity) in wikipedia ? I'll help you, this is what it says : _the speed of light in free space has the same value c in all **inertial** frames of reference._ Got it now ?

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas You are correct if you measure it non locally, but it will always be locally c.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas so, to answer your original question, that I hope I understand now: the objects that move with the hubble flow are considered inertial, so you cannot considered a non inertial character to justify a velocity larger than c. It is just that general relativity is different than SR, where spacetime is static. GR behaves like SR but only locally

Comment: I don't like terms "local/non-local", they are vague. It's like saying that your yard is local, but your neighbour's yard is non-local. What about fence in-between,- will it be "partly local" ? And it can change if yards move,- at the BigBang everything was local, but at the end of BigRip scenario - everything will become non-local. This will be the true end of light speed $c$, locality and causality overall,- because there will be no regions of space which can exchange information.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas "local" means "if you make the experiment in a lab that is small enough,  then whatever effect you are calling non local, is below the error threshold for detection".

Comment: Again you miss my point. Labs has nothing to do with this. At the start of BigBang, distances between any events was so tiny that you can call such system "local", albeit at that time there was no any labs around, right ? On the other hand if BigRip scenario is true,- in the end of it even atom's nuclei will be torn apart, including spacetime itself, so again there will be no labs which could measure non-locality everywhere in the last zepto seconds, okay ? But it will be non-locality everywhere due to universe infinite scale factor.

Comment: And if we take quantum entanglement as an example,- a pair of labs at "Alice" and "Bob" sites will measure instant wavefunction collapse in an entangled particles and will call this effect "non-local" due to labs separation. However, for quantum entangled particles this effect IS local, because they are not limited to light cone causality. So to say they "don't feels" the distance between them. The moral of the story is that "local" and "non-local" are _relative_ and vague concepts, which are abused in Physics too much, IMHO.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas Sure, you are entitled to your own opinion.

Comment: @Krokodil I missed the second question in one of your comments. I said light moving "toward us" will looks as moving away from us, I meant that, locally, the light is moving in our direction, however there is so much empty space added in between that light ray and us that the total distance is increasing, thus I called that moving "away from us". The words I used might be confusing, but I think you understand the idea because it is a consequence of teh first paragraph that you did get correctly. So the apparent direction fo motion is a function of two factors:

Comment: 1) the actual direction of motion across  space as seen locally  and 2) The amount of space added in between, really unrelated to motion, but only to apparent motion, its contribution to the apparent motion is due to the increase in distance even in the absence of actual local motion.

Comment: @PatoGalmarini I completely understand, thank you for this. And that is why I accepted your answer!

Answer (score 3):

The observable universe gets bigger with each new advance in telescope technology. In this sense the "observable universe" is that part of it which is sending just enough photons our way to trigger a pixel inside our most sensitive telescope's detector system.

Ultimately, for any part of the universe to be visible to us requires that it be transparent, so any light given off by an object there can make it out and then travel to our telescopes. Because the earlier back in time you go the hotter and denser the universe becomes then means that there will be an early time when the universe was too hot and dense for light to travel freely through it. Anything that happened before that time (the epoch is called *recombination*) then is unobservable to us, no matter how sensitive our telescopes might be.

Comment: The observable universe *includes* things that could be observed with neutrinos or gravitational waves.

Comment: @ProfRob but can we image neutrinos?

Comment: @nielsnielsen, yes: https://arxiv.org/abs/2309.10493.

Comment: So after enough time, you're saying light from those distant objects could in fact be detected by us because currently the universe is largely transparent?

Comment: Yes, it is the transparency of the universe that lets photons from the recombination era travel unimpeded to us. In fact, the cosmic microwave background is exactly the relic radiation left over from recombination.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla, that does not constitute imaging as such; what I am interested in is taking pictures of neutrino sources, like sn1987a, using neutrinos

Comment: @nielsnielsen is this true even when by "observable universe" I mean the Hubble sphere? Sorry for my bad terminology in the initial question.

Comment: I don't know what exactly is meant by "hubble sphere". so I can't answer that.